# Limit of a series involving logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms

Given series $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \log \left( \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

I wish to find the limit. Root test shows that limit exists. I tried expanding it 
$$\log(1)^\frac{1}{n} + \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} + \log\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} + \dots$$ but could not find any pattern in order to simplify. Do I need to use any other method other than the usual ones?

Comment: Hint: Think Riemann sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{i=0}^n \log \lgroup \lgroup1+\frac{i}{n}\rgroup ^\frac{1}{n}\rgroup= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n \log (1+\frac{i}{n}) \to \int_0^1 \log(1+x) dx$

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the required answer. My mind was hovering around regarding something that involved integrals but couldn't land at Riemann sums.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following inequality: ${(1+x)}$$\le$${e^x}$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \ln \left( \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$\lt$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{^\frac{1}{n}}\sum_{i=0}^n \ln \left(e^{{i\over n}}\right)$=

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{^\frac{1}{n^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n{({i})}$ - where the sum is equal to the sum of the first ${n}$ integer numbers.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ ${^\frac{1}{n^2}}$ $\frac{\left({n+1}\right)n}{2}$=$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $\left({1\over2}+{1\over2n}\right)$=$1\over2$

Finally

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \ln \left( \left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)$$\lt$$1\over2$